# IOError: [Errno 0] Error, in python file handling

Tags: python, file, file-handling

```
    with open(host_temp,'r+') as file:
            content=file.read()
            print(content)
            file.write(redirect+ " "+web + "\n")
```

This Code always shows :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "./website_blocker.py", line 4, in 
        file.write(redirect+ " "+web + "\n")
    IOError: [Errno 0] Error
```

How can solve this problem???

Comment: it is not copy pasted question, when I got tht problem then I asked that question in platform.

Comment: I used "r+" as well as "a+" after all the problem is not solved. When I used "w+" then it works but truncate all the data from files and write what I instructed in the program.